# jQuery not doing what I want it to do

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a little jQuery, and thought someone in the community could help me out? So, my markup is as follows:

```
<div class="left">
    <ul id="editing-nav">
        <li><a class="active testforso" href="#TestForSO">Test For SO</a></li>
        <li><a class="testforso2" href="#TestForSO2">Test For SO2</a></li>
        ...and so on.
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="scroll">
    <div class="scrollContainer">
        <div id="testforso">
            ...some content
        </div>
        <div id="testforso2">
            ...some content
        </div>
        ...and so on.
    </div>
</div>
```

So, basically - .left is floated left, and .scroll is on the right side. I am looking for a way so the active nav element (by default, the first one, and then when the user would click another one, it'd assign that element a class of ".active" and remove the previous one's active class)'s co-insiding div has a display:block, while all others hide. I'm doing this inside of fancybox, which makes it a little bit more complicated, but here's what I have now -

```
$('#editing-nav li > a').click(function() {
        $('#editing-nav li > a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        activeClassID = $(this).attr('class');  // grabs the nav class for the id to show in .scroll
        var divIDToShow = ('.scroll .scrollContainer #') + activeClassID;       // grabs the DOM path & ID of the coinciding div to show
            divIDToShow = divIDToShow.replace(' active', ''); // removes " active" from the class (because before it would have a class of "testforso2 active"; now it just has "testforso".
        $('.scrollContainer div:not(#' + divIDToShow + ')').hide();
        $('.scrollContainer #' + divIDToShow ).show();
    });
```

This works for the first link someone clicks, but not after that. I don't know if I was clear earlier, but the class for the #editing-nav li a co-incides with what div to show inside of .scroll.

Any ideas? I'm not sure why it's doing this... Thank you!

Comment: you may want to include a return false or e.preventDefault for the click - otherwise you may get some jumping in some (probably few) cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is with your id selector - try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq8T3/) instead

**EDIT**

Figured out the real issue here - not sure why it works the first time but your `divIDToShow` variable contains too much information. See [here for a cut down version](http://jsfiddle.net/rPg6d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's doing this is probably because it ran into an error during the first click. `'active testforso'.replace(' active')` evaluates to `'active testforso'` because there is no `' active'` in the string. Even if you fix that, you don't know whether 'active' is in front or at the back of the class string. You could instead do `.replace(/\s*active\s*/, '')` , but my example below just removes all spaces.

I think you could probably change your code to something like:

```
$('#editing-nav li > a').click(function() {
    $('#editing-nav li > a:active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    activeClassID = $(this).attr('class');  // grabs the nav class for the id to show in .scroll
    var divIDToShow = activeClassID;       // grabs the DOM path & ID of the coinciding div to show
    divIDToShow = divIDToShow.replace('active', '').replace(/\s+/g,''); // removes "active" from the class then remove all spaces in what's left - "testforso2 active"; now it just has "testforso".
    $('.scrollContainer div:not(#' + divIDToShow + ')').hide();
    $('#' + divIDToShow ).show();
});
```

### BUT:

Instead of doing all these, you might want to use the [jQuery-BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) which allows you to track states through the hash. So you can just detect changes in the hash like, for example, using the hash as the id itself.

Comment: a good answer but seems overly complicated. if this is the case could he not set the var divToShow before he adds the active class? Then he will not need to do a replace at all

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it is rather complicated. I wanted to keep it to as little modification as possible. As I stated in the BUT, other methods are definitely more attractive than this.